# MAX FROM COUNT in HQL

Tags: count, hql, max

I have Doctor and Patient classes, where every doctor has some patients (1:m). 
How do I find the doctor (or doctors) with the most patients in HQL?

Here the SQL query:

`SELECT D.doctorName, count(D.patientId) AS tot
FROM Doctors AS D GROUP BY D.doctorName HAVING count(D.patientId)= 
(SELECT max(A.pid) FROM( SELECT count(D.patientId) AS pid FROM Doctors AS D
GROUP BY D.doctorName) AS A)`

The main issue is that I cannot write a sub-query in FROM place.

Many thanks.

R

Comment: I don't think that query does what you think it does. Consider the case where multiple doctors have the same number of patients.

Comment: No, I mean for example one doctor has two (different) patients, and another doctor has two (again different) patients. So altogether there are two different doctors and four different patients. No duplicates.

Comment: The answer will be
doctor 1 - 2 (patients)
doctor 2 - 2 (patients)
but it doesn't matter (if 2 is the max value), it's ok. 
The main problem is how to convert the 'SELECT max() FROM (subquery)' in HQL. TK

Comment: If that's actually what you want then I'd suggest rewording the question from "the Doctor with more patients" to "the doctor (or doctors) with the most patients", so that it matches what the query actually does. Currently your question doesn't match the query. I think it's important that the  question is clear.

Comment: done! I changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I've created a CRITERIA function to replace the subquery. Not elegant but works!

```
    def myList = []
    String tempName = ""
    int patPosition = 0
    int myListPosition = -1
    int find = 0
    int maxOcc = 0

    def c = Doctor.createCriteria()
    def pat = c.list {              
        patients {          
        }
    }

    while(patPosition<pat.size()){

        find=0
        tempName=pat[patPosition].lastName //Some constraints to add 
        find=pat.lastName.count(tempName)

        if(find>maxOcc){
            maxOcc=find
        }

        myListPosition=myListPosition+1
        myList[myListPosition]=find

        patPosition=patPosition+find

    }

    print "\n\nLIST -> "+myList
    print "MAX -> "+maxOcc

    String queryToDo=   "SELECT d.name, count(p) "+
                        "FROM Doctor as d INNER JOIN d.patients as p "+
                        "GROUP BY d.name "+
                        "HAVING count(p) = $maxOcc" 

    def query = Doctor.executeQuery(queryToDo)  
    render query
```

Answer (score 0):

More synthetic:

```
pat.eachWithIndex{item, index-> 
          if (index.equals(index2)){
            patCount=0
            patCount=pat.count(item)    
            index2=index2+patCount
                if(patCount>maxOcc){
                    maxOcc=patCount
                }
          } 
     }
```